# how to auto_increment char datatype depending upon the prefix of the record?

Tags: mysql

I have a **customer** table,  the fields in the table are **id_customer**, **name**, **birthday**.

The **id_customer** datatype is CHAR(20) and the format is '**CUSTyyyymmdd00000000**' the **yyyymmdd** in the id is the customer's birthday. The last 8 digit is increased based on the birthday on the id_customer field.

the output example :
**CUST1995020100000001, CUST1995020100000002, CUST1995030300000001, CUST1995030300000002** and so on.

I already created a function to increase the last digit :

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE
    FUNCTION get_increment_id_cust()
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE id INT;
    SET id =( SELECT IFNULL(MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(id_customer,8),INT)),0) AS id
             FROM customer );
    RETURN id+1;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and with this code :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONCAT('00000000',get_increment_id_cust()),LENGTH(CONCAT('00000000',get_increment_id_cust()))-7,8);
```

i have the 8 digit like 00000001, 00000002 and so on.

I've tried to use another concat to add the prefix, but it cant add a different birthday.

And how do i implement it on Before Insert Trigger so it's increased automatically when i add another row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that you depart from your current approach, and instead maintain a table including the following two columns:

```
(id, date_of_birth, ...)
```

That is, just store the date of birth in a separate bona-fide column.  As for the ID value, you may rely on an auto increment column, which MySQL guarantees will always generate a new unique value.  If you still have the need for an `id_customer`, as you have described it, you may always generate it when you query, e.g.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('CUST', DATE_FORMAT(date_of_birth, '%Y%m%d'), id) AS id_customer
FROM yourTable;
```

Your `id_customer` consists of several different parts, each of which really belongs in a separate column.  I suggest the above to simplify your maintenance and make your life easier.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for the roundabout format, it is a homework from my teacher, so i cant really break it down to separate column.

Comment: @AllandChandraKesuma I didn't know this was actual homework.  I will leave my answer up though, because in practice it is not a bad way to go IMO.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your suggestion, it might help other people too as it is not wrong at all.